# merge static methods with annotation processing and javapoet

Tags: java, annotation-processing, javapoet

I have static methods in multiple classes that I want to merge in a new, generated, class for convenience reasons.

I am using annotation processing and javapoet.

My Problem: from annotation processing, I get the static methods as a list of ExecutableElements.

For JavaPoet, I need to create MethodSpecs of those. I am trying:

```
 public MethodSpec apply(@Nullable ExecutableElement input) {
  TypeMirror returnType = input.getReturnType();

  return MethodSpec.methodBuilder(THE_METHOD_NAME)
    .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.STATIC)
    .returns(THE_RETURN_TYPE)
    .addParameter(EVERY_PARAMETER_WITH_TYPE_AND_NAME)
    .addStatement("$T.$S($S)", THE_ENCLOSING_CLASS, THE_METHOD_NAME, THE_PARAMETERS)
    .build();
}
```

My question: How to I get Type-values for the missing words in CAPS? Seems like the ExecutableElements do not behave like reflection api.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a schematic code that you can use to get you started:

`THE_METHOD_NAME` -> `input.getSimpleName()`

`THE_RETURN_TYPE` -> `input.getReturnType()`

`THE_ENCLOSING_CLASS` -> `input.getEnclosingElement().getSimpleName()`

`EVERY_PARAMETER_WITH_TYPE_AND_NAME` ->

```
for (VariableElement ve: executableElement.getParameters()){
   System.out.println("Param name: " + ve.getSimpleName());
   // note here that the type can be generic, so you'll need to parse 
   // the generic part and use to build a javapoet 
   // ParameterizedTypeName
   System.out.println("Param type: " + ve.asType());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But as you see in the code above, getReturnType is of type "TypeMirror" ... If I pass this to javapoet, I will get a TypeMirror return ...

Comment: `com.squareup.javapoet.ClassName` can be used to build up a type from the string representation of the output of `ve.asType()` . I assumed this when writing, based on the sample code taken from [javapoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet)